# Trouble Verifying Enterprise Apps

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios9

I have, in the past, downloaded an Enterprise app to use. I did all required steps, including trusting the developer and verifying the application. After this, the app worked fine. Recently, however, when I attempted to use it, it said "/x/ has not been trusted on this device. Until this developer has been trusted, their enterprise apps will not be available to use. Upon going to Settings, in the tab for this developer, it said that this developer has been trusted, but the applications must be verified. I pushed "Verify App", however the only thing that happened was the name of the developer at the top of the screen changing to "Verifying..." for a split second. The app still said "Not Verified". I am connected to a stable network. Does anyone know what could be causing this problem, and if there is a fix?

Comment: I too had the issue. It disappeared when I connected to wifi and tried to approve the App. Also make sure you are logged in to iTunes when you try to verify it.